# How can I get value from a select inserted by jQuery

Tags: jquery, select

I want to get a value from a select, but this select it was inserted by a jQuery.html(), like this:

```
$("#brand").change(function () {
  var _marca = $("#marca").val();
  $.post("http://www.url.com/ajax/get_year", {brand:_brand}, function (data) {
    $("#year").html(data);
  });
});

$("#year").change(function () {
  var _brand = $("#brand").val();
  var _year = $("#year").val();
  alert(_year); // To check the value, it's null always...
  $.post("http://www.url.com/ajax/get_model", {brand:_brand, year:_year}, function (data) {
    $("#model").html(data);
  });
});
```

And my HTML code:

```
<select name="brand" id="brand">
<option value="1">Brand 1</option>
</select>

<select id="year"></div>

<select id="model"></div>
```

The first select works, but the second one only load, if I try to change to another option, the alert function does not show anything.

How can I get the correct value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

This is the new ( mmmm now it's old) way for `live` which means :

> Register the event not only for existing elements but also  for the future  ones.

```
$("body").on('change','#year',function (){
 var _brand = $("#brand").val();
  var _year = $("#year").val();
  alert(_year); // To check the value, it's null always...
  $.post("http://www.url.com/ajax/get_model", {brand:_brand, year:_year}, function (data) {
    $("#model").html(data);
  });
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used that code and still showing null using alert function, I tried on() and live(). I do no have idea about how to correct it.

Comment: how does `data` looks like after the `$.post` ?

Comment: The alert is before $.post and it does not have any value, but after $.post only print a select with id="year" and data filtered by brand and year. So I have to send both values but only brand have something.

Comment: I want something like that, the problem is what I have to hide the other selects, and I know I can use hide() and show() but first I would want to see another options. I will use your code, and hide or show my selects depending of action, thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean "to hide/show"  ? You didn't mention this in your question. please tell me what/when you want to hide/show.

Comment: You published an example, but in this case you always show both selects, my problem was I need to show only one, and when it change show another. Your first code works perfectly, I had not seen that the id from my div container it was the same from my select, and so it was not working, but right now my application works, thanks a lot.